# Deleting JPanel and replacing with another in JFrame doesn't work. New JPanel not diplayed

Tags: swing, user-interface, resize, jframe, jpanel

I'm writing a java project in which I have to build multiple interfaces. I'm using a JFrame class and a number of JPanel classes, one for each interface.

The idea is to replace from time to time the JPanel diplayed by the JFrame class, showing every time the requested interface.

One of the problems is that every JPanel has different size from the others, so I need to resize the JFrame at every change. More specificly: the JFrame contain a jScrollPane, and every JPanel has to be added to this Scroll Panel.

When I run the application and load the first interface it goes ahead without problem, then I resize the JFrame, delete the precedent JPanel, add the new one... and nothing! After the deleting of the first JPanel I'm not able to add any other component (JPanel, JButton... nothing!).

The resize goes without problems, and after that nothing: I'm still able to modify frame properties with success, but i can't visualize any new JPanel or component, and the Scroll Panel itself seems to be not in the JFrame.

Here is the code.

JFrame class:

```
package gestione_temi_esame;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 *
 * @author Pellini
 */
public class GUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    protected static GUI app = new GUI();
    protected static JPanel saluto = new welcome();
    protected static JPanel login_fase1 = new login_us_pw();
    protected static JPanel login_fase2 = new login_corso();
    /**
     * Creates new form GUI
     */
    public GUI() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        GUI.this.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent windowEvent) {
                if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(GUI.this, "Sei sicuro di voler chiudere l'applicazione?", "Chiudere?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE) == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                System.exit(0);

            }
        });
        jscrollpane_GUI = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1920, 1080));
        setResizable(false);

        jscrollpane_GUI.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1920, 1080));
        jscrollpane_GUI.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(410, 300));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jscrollpane_GUI, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jscrollpane_GUI, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }// </editor-fold>                        





    private static void benvenuto() {

        app.removeNotify();
        app.setUndecorated(true); 
        app.addNotify();
        app.setSize(410, 300);
        app.jscrollpane_GUI.setSize(410, 300);
        app.setVisible(true);
        app.jscrollpane_GUI.add(saluto);
        //Trascorsi 5 secondi, chiudo la schermata di benvenuto e carico la schermata di login
        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run () { 

                app.jscrollpane_GUI.remove(saluto);
                login();

            }
        }, 1000);

    }

    private static void login() {
        app.removeNotify();
        app.setUndecorated(false); 
        app.setResizable(true);
        app.addNotify();
        app.setSize(640, 480);       
        app.jscrollpane_GUI.setSize(640, 480);  
        app.setTitle("Gestione Temi d'Esame - Login");
        app.setLocationRelativeTo(null);   

        app.jscrollpane_GUI.add(login_fase1);
        //app.jscrollpane_GUI.validate();
        //app.jscrollpane_GUI.repaint();


    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
/*        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

            }
        });*/

        benvenuto();  

    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jscrollpane_GUI;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

first JPanel class:

```
package gestione_temi_esame;

/**
 *
 * @author Pellini
 */
public class welcome extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    /**
     * Creates new form welcome
     */
    public welcome() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        panel_welcome = new java.awt.Panel();
        lbl_nome = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        lbl_versione = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        label_welcome_img = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(410, 300));

        panel_welcome.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(410, 300));
        panel_welcome.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(410, 300));

        lbl_nome.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 26)); // NOI18N
        lbl_nome.setText("Gestione Temi d'Esame");

        lbl_versione.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        lbl_versione.setText("v 1.0");

        label_welcome_img.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/gestione_temi_esame/rsz_welcome_img.jpg"))); // NOI18N
        label_welcome_img.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(114, 190));
        label_welcome_img.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(114, 190));
        label_welcome_img.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(114, 190));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout panel_welcomeLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(panel_welcome);
        panel_welcome.setLayout(panel_welcomeLayout);
        panel_welcomeLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            panel_welcomeLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(panel_welcomeLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(label_welcome_img, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGroup(panel_welcomeLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(panel_welcomeLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(lbl_nome, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 270, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addContainerGap())
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, panel_welcomeLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(lbl_versione)
                        .addGap(81, 81, 81))))
        );
        panel_welcomeLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            panel_welcomeLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(panel_welcomeLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(panel_welcomeLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(panel_welcomeLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(label_welcome_img, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(panel_welcomeLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(94, 94, 94)
                        .addComponent(lbl_nome, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 48, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(27, 27, 27)
                        .addComponent(lbl_versione)))
                .addContainerGap(99, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 410, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(panel_welcome, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(panel_welcome, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
        );
    }// </editor-fold>                        


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel label_welcome_img;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lbl_nome;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lbl_versione;
    private java.awt.Panel panel_welcome;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Second JPanel class:

```
package gestione_temi_esame;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.util.Map;
import java.awt.font.TextAttribute;
import java.awt.Cursor;

/**
 *
 * @author Pellini
 */
public class login_us_pw extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    /**
     * Creates new form login_us_pw
     */
    public login_us_pw() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        Font font;
        Map attributes;
        jpanel_contenitore = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jlabel_inserisci_credenziali = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jlabel_username = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jtextfield_username = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jbutton_helpus = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jbutton_helppw = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jpasswordfield_password = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
        jlabel_password = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jbutton_login = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jlabel_recupero_link = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jlabel_recupero = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jlabel_registrazione = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jlabel_registrazione_link = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(620, 460));
        setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(620, 460));

        jpanel_contenitore.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(628, 468));

        jlabel_inserisci_credenziali.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jlabel_inserisci_credenziali.setText("Per accedere all'applicazione inserisci le tue credenziali");
        jlabel_inserisci_credenziali.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(437, 29));
        jlabel_inserisci_credenziali.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(437, 29));
        jlabel_inserisci_credenziali.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(437, 29));

        jlabel_username.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
        jlabel_username.setText("Username:");
        jlabel_username.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(90, 29));
        jlabel_username.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(90, 29));
        jlabel_username.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(90, 29));

        jtextfield_username.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jtextfield_username.setFocusTraversalPolicyProvider(true);
        jtextfield_username.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(227, 33));
        jtextfield_username.addFocusListener(new java.awt.event.FocusAdapter() {
            public void focusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
                jtextfield_usernameFocusLost(evt);
            }
        });

        jbutton_helpus.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
        jbutton_helpus.setText("?");
        jbutton_helpus.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));
        jbutton_helpus.setFocusTraversalPolicyProvider(true);
        jbutton_helpus.setMargin(new java.awt.Insets(2, 2, 2, 2));
        jbutton_helpus.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(18, 18));
        jbutton_helpus.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(18, 18));
        jbutton_helpus.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(18, 18));
        jbutton_helpus.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jbutton_helpusActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jlabel_recupero.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 13)); // NOI18N
        jlabel_recupero.setText("Hai dimenticato username e/o password?");
        jlabel_recupero.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(242, 23));
        jlabel_recupero.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(242, 23));
        jlabel_recupero.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(242, 23));

        jlabel_registrazione.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 13)); // NOI18N
        jlabel_registrazione.setText("Non sei ancora registrato?");
        jlabel_registrazione.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(161, 23));
        jlabel_registrazione.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(161, 23));
        jlabel_registrazione.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(161, 23));

        jlabel_registrazione_link.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 13)); // NOI18N
        jlabel_registrazione_link.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 255));
        jlabel_registrazione_link.setText("Clicca qui");
        jlabel_registrazione_link.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(59, 23));
        jlabel_registrazione_link.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(59, 23));
        jlabel_registrazione_link.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(59, 23));
        font = jlabel_registrazione_link.getFont();
        attributes = font.getAttributes();
        attributes.put(TextAttribute.UNDERLINE, TextAttribute.UNDERLINE_ON);
        jlabel_registrazione_link.setFont(font.deriveFont(attributes));
        jlabel_registrazione_link.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        jlabel_registrazione_link.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jlabel_registrazione_linkMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jpanel_contenitoreLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jpanel_contenitore);
        jpanel_contenitore.setLayout(jpanel_contenitoreLayout);
        jpanel_contenitoreLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jpanel_contenitoreLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jpanel_contenitoreLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jpanel_contenitoreLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jpanel_contenitoreLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(124, 124, 124)
                        .addGroup(jpanel_contenitoreLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(jpanel_contenitoreLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jlabel_password, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 90, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                .addComponent(jpasswordfield_password, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 227, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                .addComponent(jbutton_helppw, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGroup(jpanel_contenitoreLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(jpanel_contenitoreLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addGroup(jpanel_contenitoreLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(jlabel_registrazione, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 149, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                        .addComponent(jlabel_registrazione_link, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                    .addComponent(jlabel_recupero, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 226, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(jlabel_recupero_link, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGroup(jpanel_contenitoreLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jlabel_username, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 90, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                .addComponent(jtextfield_username, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 227, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                .addComponent(jbutton_helpus, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                    .addGroup(jpanel_contenitoreLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(98, 98, 98)
                        .addComponent(jlabel_inserisci_credenziali, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 437, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(85, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jpanel_contenitoreLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jbutton_login, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(191, 191, 191))
        );
        jpanel_contenitoreLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            jpanel_contenitoreLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jpanel_contenitoreLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(86, 86, 86)
                .addComponent(jlabel_inserisci_credenziali, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 29, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(54, 54, 54)
                .addGroup(jpanel_contenitoreLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jlabel_username, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jtextfield_username, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 33, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jbutton_helpus, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                .addGroup(jpanel_contenitoreLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jlabel_password, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 29, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jbutton_helppw, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jpasswordfield_password, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 33, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(29, 29, 29)
                .addComponent(jbutton_login, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 35, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(jpanel_contenitoreLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jlabel_recupero, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jlabel_recupero_link, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(jpanel_contenitoreLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jlabel_registrazione, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jlabel_registrazione_link, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(44, 44, 44))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jpanel_contenitore, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jpanel_contenitore, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jbutton_helppw;
    private javax.swing.JButton jbutton_helpus;
    private javax.swing.JButton jbutton_login;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jlabel_inserisci_credenziali;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jlabel_password;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jlabel_recupero;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jlabel_recupero_link;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jlabel_registrazione;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jlabel_registrazione_link;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jlabel_username;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jpanel_contenitore;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField jpasswordfield_password;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jtextfield_username;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

I've searched everywhere, in this forum as in others, trying everything (as you can see for example with the commented validate() method), but it still doesn't work.

After deleting the first JPanel and resizing the JFrame, i'll see only an empty JFrame window, without any component.

Thanks to everybody can help me!

Comment: Use a [Card Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) which is designed for swapping panels.

Comment: 1) See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)  Often what is needed is actually layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 2) Fully agree with @camickr on using a `CardLayout` for this. It is made for flipping views.